# Xcode awfully slow

Tags: xcode

This is very frustrating. Xcode 6.x is slow as a turtle occasionally. All versions I 've tried, the normal, the beta one.

I 've

- Turned "live issues" off
- Checked overall performance, it's fine, not a lot of HDD access
- 4GB of RAM + another 2GB for a ram disk in which output is sent, still problem
- Closed the "right panel" of the properties.
- Resetted the workspace

This is a project with over 100 source files. What could I do?

It starts slowing down as long as I try to open a file from the list at the left.

Note that it is very slow even on file scroll down/up, or when searching with Ctrl+F etc.

Comment: I'm feeling you pain, but the 4GB seems to be an issue. I've got 8 now and it is a little but better. Seem my Mac (27-inch, Mid 2011) is getting to old mayby.

Comment: It does not use all the memory anyway.