# Xcode 11.2.1 unuseably slow

Tags: xcode

Xcode 11.2.1 unuseably slow starting and compiling the project.

Is there a recourse other than uninstall and fallback to last known semi-useable version such as 11.2.1GM or 11.1 ?

Might be a new installment of the age old saga [Xcode awfully slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27295664/xcode-awfully-slow)

Comment: Hi Anton, are you running any third party “endpoint security” software? there is a known issue that can cause slowness with Xcode 11.2 if so.

Comment: Xcode relnotes were saying the issue is in xcode<-> lldb communication, you are saying the issue is more widespread than this?

Comment: See this the link under Simulator -> Known Issues. - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_2_release_notes 

The solution is to uninstall the third-party software. Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: got rid of Kasperksy (in violation of the company security policy). Stay tuned.

Answer (score 1):

**There is a known issue in Xcode 11.2 with the simulator:**

See in the [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_2_release_notes):

> **Known Issues**
>
> Third party “endpoint security” software may cause slow
> simulators, system freezes, or prevent debug processes from running in
> simulators reliably. This sometimes manifests as debugserver
> disconnections or simulator applications receiving a SIGKILL signal.
> (55853555)
>
> **Workaround**: Uninstall the third party software.